# How do I see the traffic of target device in WiFi Pineapple Portal?

Tags: networking, security, wifi, hacking

[image]

I'm using Windows 10 PC connect via Ethernet cable.
I also connect my WiFi pine apple nano into my PC, and configure :

- Ethernet sharing to share internet connection through : PineApple
- PineApple, update IPv4 to use `172.16.42.42`

## WiFi Pineapple Portal

I was able to :

- connect to the WiFi, and get an IP Address,
- successfully load the bullentins board from Hak5.
- successfully bradcast my **Open** SSID
- successfully broadcast my Open SSID (LR wifi)
- see the connected client in the Clients list, but I have no idea to see the traffic that the client visit.

[image]

## Device

I was able to connect, get an IP, but can also browse.

How do I see the traffic of target device in WiFi Pineapple Portal  ? Do I need to download other module like **ethercap** ?

Answer (score 1):

You need an extra utility like Ettercap or wireshark.

Comment: In my opinion you are right, but an explanation (including some links maybe) for the unknowning would be a lot more helpful.